# Can't edit message in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I wanted to make a custom bot for discord using nodejs and it's been 4 hours and I can't get this to work.

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1234567890');
    channel.fetchMessage('0987654321').then(message => 
        message.edit(output(msg)));
    })
```

I want to edit a specific message based on the input (msg).
I already have the output(msg) function ready in javascript.
I just can't put the output into the specific message.
Any help pls...

Edit (for extra info):

Pretty sure `channel` does return a channel

The current error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchMessage')
```

output(msg) will return a string

**TLDR: how to I edit a message if I have it's id**

Comment: You are missing `})` in the end of that code, or did you just not include it?

Comment: What version of discord are you using, and what debugging have you done so far? Does `channel` return a channel? Have you confirmed `fetchMessage()` is resolving? What is the output of `output(msg)`

Comment: `channel` is `undefined`. Make sure it's cached and the ID is correct